# Why does A New Memory Card Needs to be Formatted Before Use?

Tags: memory, formatting, format, memory-card

Why does a new memory card or flash drive need to be formatted before using it?

All of I get from internet is just a tip to format it before use.

But they don't explain why we need to format it first.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why we need to format a memory card before using it?

In order to write user data (files or directories) to a memory card (or other kinds of storage devices) we need to have a [File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) in place to receive the data.

[Formatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting) prepares the storage medium to receive files and adds a File System.

---

#### What is a File System?

> In computing, a file system or filesystem is used to control how data is stored and retrieved.
>
> - Without a file system, information placed in a storage medium would be one large body of data with no way to tell where one piece of information stops and the next begins.
> - By separating the data into pieces and giving each piece a name, the information is easily isolated and identified.

Source [File system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)

---

#### What a Format actually do?

> Disk formatting is the process of preparing a data storage device such as a hard disk drive, solid-state drive, floppy disk or USB flash drive for initial use. In some cases, the formatting operation may also create one or more new file systems.
>
> - The first part of the formatting process that performs basic medium preparation is often referred to as "low-level formatting".
> - Partitioning is the common term for the second part of the process, making the data storage device visible to an operating system.
> - The third part of the process, usually termed "high-level formatting" most often refers to the process of generating a new file system.
>
> In some operating systems all or parts of these three processes can be combined or repeated at different levels and the term "format" is understood to mean an operation in which a new disk medium is fully prepared to store files.

Source [Disk formatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting)

Comment: That last paragraph seems a bit off – most memory cards (nor disks) don't allow accessing the internals to do an actual low-level format; the most that a "Format" option does is write a partition table and a new FS.

Comment: @grawity Well [HDD LLF Low Level Format Tool](http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-LLF-Low-Level-Format-Tool/) claims to do it.

Comment: @DavidPostill They're mistaken... unless they're talking about ancient stuff like ST506 or ESDI disks. Ever since ATA and SCSI disks the only people who can do a true low level format are at the factory. There are no commands you can give to the ATA or SCSI interface to do it.